# 2 same (function,class) name "Ajax" in prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, ref

In the project I am working on uses established and then used in many parts

```
 function Ajax (recvType, waitId)
```

I want to use the "prototype framework" it have class Ajax
 it is better to do and where to change ?
or change in prototype and afte using another name instead Ajax some else name?
Or change in all project ?
or is there a way to produce two desired method with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype has a [class named Ajax](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax). This is bound to create conflicts with your existing class.

I would strongly recommend renaming your class. Renaming Prototype's Ajax class is a lot of work, you'd have to repeat it for every new version, and it may break other plugins relying on it.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NzpL6/) throwing an error